# Getting error while unpacking iso message

Tags: java, bitmap, unpack, iso8583, jpos

I have shared required details in the tail, I packed ISO message of title fetch (0210) which contains all the required feilds i.e 2,3,4,7,11,12,13,15,18,22,24,32,33,37,38,39,41,43,49,103,120. but we are getting error while we unpack the data it says to me that on 120 feild it requires 268 bytes although i am setting appropriate bytes but still i am getting this error, Can any one guide me on this?

```
Error while parsing. Parsed Incoming Body Fields :
EXT-ID[2]       FLD[Primary Account Number..]  FRMT[LL-VARCHAR]         LL[2]  LEN[19]   DATA[9999170003354140609]
EXT-ID[3]       FLD[Processing Code]           FRMT[Fixed-Format-Gr..]  LL[0]  LEN[6]    DATA[620000]
+EXT-ID[1]      FLD[Transaction type]          FRMT[Fixed Format]       LL[0]  LEN[2]    DATA[62]
+EXT-ID[2]      FLD[From Account type]         FRMT[Fixed Format]       LL[0]  LEN[2]    DATA[00]
+EXT-ID[3]      FLD[To Account type ]          FRMT[Fixed Format]       LL[0]  LEN[2]    DATA[00]
EXT-ID[4]       FLD[Amount, Transaction ]      FRMT[Fixed Format]       LL[0]  LEN[12]   DATA[000000100000]
EXT-ID[7]       FLD[Transmission Date and ..]  FRMT[Fixed Format]       LL[0]  LEN[10]   DATA[0301103145]
EXT-ID[11]      FLD[System Trace Audit Num..]  FRMT[Fixed Format]       LL[0]  LEN[6]    DATA[017564]
EXT-ID[12]      FLD[Time, Local Transactio..]  FRMT[Fixed Format]       LL[0]  LEN[6]    DATA[103145]
EXT-ID[13]      FLD[Date, Local Transactio..]  FRMT[Fixed Format]       LL[0]  LEN[4]    DATA[0301]
EXT-ID[15]      FLD[Date, Settlement]          FRMT[Fixed Format]       LL[0]  LEN[4]    DATA[0302]
EXT-ID[18]      FLD[Merchant Type ]            FRMT[Fixed Format]       LL[0]  LEN[4]    DATA[0003]
EXT-ID[22]      FLD[Point-of-Service Entry..]  FRMT[Fixed Format]       LL[0]  LEN[3]    DATA[901]
EXT-ID[24]      FLD[Network Institution Id..]  FRMT[Fixed Format]       LL[0]  LEN[3]    DATA[001]
EXT-ID[32]      FLD[Acquiring Institution ..]  FRMT[LL-VARCHAR]         LL[2]  LEN[11]   DATA[16049800000]
EXT-ID[33]      FLD[Forwarding Institution..]  FRMT[LL-VARCHAR]         LL[2]  LEN[6]    DATA[000001]
EXT-ID[37]      FLD[Retrieval Reference Nu..]  FRMT[Fixed Format]       LL[0]  LEN[12]   DATA[314500000018]
EXT-ID[38]      FLD[Authorization Identifi..]  FRMT[Fixed Format]       LL[0]  LEN[6]    DATA[083364]
EXT-ID[39]      FLD[Response Code]             FRMT[Fixed Format]       LL[0]  LEN[2]    DATA[00]
EXT-ID[41]      FLD[Card Acceptor Terminal..]  FRMT[Fixed Format]       LL[0]  LEN[8]    DATA[12345678]
EXT-ID[43]      FLD[Card Acceptor Name and..]  FRMT[Fixed Format]       LL[0]  LEN[40]   DATA[Suite 211 212 Park Towers      KARACHI00]
EXT-ID[49]      FLD[Currency Code, Transac..]  FRMT[Fixed Format]       LL[0]  LEN[3]    DATA[586]
EXT-ID[103]     FLD[Account Identification..]  FRMT[LL-VARCHAR]         LL[2]  LEN[11]   DATA[03330252674]

10:28:00.304 ERROR [MsgParser:ListProc-Q0:I1]   PARSING FAIL FLD [BITMAP] MSG[Out of bytes. Available: 12 bytes, required: 268 bytes]
10:28:00.304 ERROR [MapperMgr:ListProc-Q0:I1]   [UID:N/A, Message Timestamp:2022-03-01 10:31:45.663] Parsing exception on field [BITMAP]
Error mapping the fieldAdditional Information:
```

Hex Dump which i sent to server:

```
0000  00 DD 30 32 31 30 F2 3A  45 01 8E A0 80 00 00 00  ..0210.:E.......
0010  00 00 02 00 01 00 31 39  39 39 39 39 31 37 30 30  ......1999991700
0020  30 33 33 35 34 31 34 30  36 30 39 36 32 30 30 30  0335414060962000
0030  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 31  30 30 30 30 30 30 33 30  0000000100000030
0040  31 31 30 33 31 34 35 30  31 37 35 36 34 31 30 33  1103145017564103
0050  31 34 35 30 33 30 31 30  33 30 32 30 30 30 33 39  1450301030200039
0060  30 31 30 30 31 31 31 31  36 30 34 39 38 30 30 30  0100111160498000
0070  30 30 30 36 30 30 30 30  30 31 33 31 34 35 30 30  0006000001314500
0080  30 30 30 30 31 38 30 38  33 33 36 34 30 30 31 32  0000180833640012
0090  33 34 35 36 37 38 53 75  69 74 65 20 32 31 31 20  345678Suite 211
00a0  32 31 32 20 50 61 72 6B  20 54 6F 77 65 72 73 20  212 Park Towers
00b0  20 20 20 20 20 4B 41 52  41 43 48 49 30 30 35 38       KARACHI0058
00c0  36 31 31 30 33 33 33 30  32 35 32 36 37 34 32 36  6110333025267426
00d0  38 30 33 33 33 30 32 35  32 36 37 34 30 30 30 30  8033302526740000
00e0  30 30 30 30 30 48 41 52  49 53 20 4B 48 41 4C 45  00000HARIS KHALE
00f0  45 51 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  EQ00000000000000
0100  30 30 30 31 36 30 34 39  38 30 30 30 30 30 39 39  0001604980000099
0110  39 39 34 36 30 30 30 30  30 43 30 30 30 30 30 30  994600000C000000
0120  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0130  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0140  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0150  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0160  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0170  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 50 4B  00000000000000PK
0180  32 33 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 32 32 30 31  2300000000002201
0190  32 35 30 34 34 38 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  2504480000000000
01a0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
01b0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
01c0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
01d0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30           0000000000000
```

Xml file which i am using for unpacking and packing is mentioned below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!--
~  Copyright (c) 2017, WSO2 Inc. (http://wso2.com) All Rights Reserved.
~
~  WSO2 Inc. licenses this file to you under the Apache License,
~  Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
~  in compliance with the License.
~  You may obtain a copy of the License at
~
~   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
~
~  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
~  software distributed under the License is distributed on an
~  "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
~  KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
~  specific language governing permissions and limitations
~  under the License.
-->

<!DOCTYPE isopackager SYSTEM "genericpackager.dtd">

<!-- ISO 8583:1987 (ASCII) field descriptions for GenericPackager -->

<isopackager>
  <isofield
      id="0"
      length="4"
      name="MESSAGE TYPE INDICATOR"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="1"
      length="16"
      name="BIT MAP"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_BITMAP"/>
  <isofield
      id="2"
      length="19"
      name="PAN - PRIMARY ACCOUNT NUMBER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
      id="3"
      length="6"
      name="PROCESSING CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="4"
      length="12"
      name="AMOUNT, TRANSACTION"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="5"
      length="12"
      name="AMOUNT, SETTLEMENT"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="6"
      length="12"
      name="AMOUNT, CARDHOLDER BILLING"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="7"
      length="10"
      name="TRANSMISSION DATE AND TIME"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="8"
      length="8"
      name="AMOUNT, CARDHOLDER BILLING FEE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="9"
      length="8"
      name="CONVERSION RATE, SETTLEMENT"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="10"
      length="8"
      name="CONVERSION RATE, CARDHOLDER BILLING"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="11"
      length="6"
      name="SYSTEM TRACE AUDIT NUMBER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="12"
      length="6"
      name="TIME, LOCAL TRANSACTION"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="13"
      length="4"
      name="DATE, LOCAL TRANSACTION"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="14"
      length="4"
      name="DATE, EXPIRATION"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="15"
      length="4"
      name="DATE, SETTLEMENT"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="16"
      length="4"
      name="DATE, CONVERSION"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="17"
      length="4"
      name="DATE, CAPTURE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="18"
      length="4"
      name="MERCHANTS TYPE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="19"
      length="3"
      name="ACQUIRING INSTITUTION COUNTRY CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="20"
      length="3"
      name="PAN EXTENDED COUNTRY CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="21"
      length="3"
      name="FORWARDING INSTITUTION COUNTRY CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="22"
      length="3"
      name="POINT OF SERVICE ENTRY MODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="23"
      length="3"
      name="CARD SEQUENCE NUMBER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="24"
      length="3"
      name="NETWORK INTERNATIONAL IDENTIFIEER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="25"
      length="2"
      name="POINT OF SERVICE CONDITION CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="26"
      length="2"
      name="POINT OF SERVICE PIN CAPTURE CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="27"
      length="1"
      name="AUTHORIZATION IDENTIFICATION RESP LEN"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="28"
      length="9"
      name="AMOUNT, TRANSACTION FEE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_AMOUNT"/>
  <isofield
      id="29"
      length="9"
      name="AMOUNT, SETTLEMENT FEE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_AMOUNT"/>
  <isofield
      id="30"
      length="9"
      name="AMOUNT, TRANSACTION PROCESSING FEE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_AMOUNT"/>
  <isofield
      id="31"
      length="9"
      name="AMOUNT, SETTLEMENT PROCESSING FEE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_AMOUNT"/>
  <isofield
      id="32"
      length="11"
      name="ACQUIRING INSTITUTION IDENT CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
      id="33"
      length="11"
      name="FORWARDING INSTITUTION IDENT CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
      id="34"
      length="28"
      name="PAN EXTENDED"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="35"
      length="37"
      name="TRACK 2 DATA"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
      id="36"
      length="104"
      name="TRACK 3 DATA"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="37"
      length="12"
      name="RETRIEVAL REFERENCE NUMBER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="38"
      length="6"
      name="AUTHORIZATION IDENTIFICATION RESPONSE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="39"
      length="2"
      name="RESPONSE CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="40"
      length="3"
      name="SERVICE RESTRICTION CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="41"
      length="8"
      name="CARD ACCEPTOR TERMINAL IDENTIFICACION"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="42"
      length="15"
      name="CARD ACCEPTOR IDENTIFICATION CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="43"
      length="40"
      name="CARD ACCEPTOR NAME/LOCATION"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="44"
      length="25"
      name="ADITIONAL RESPONSE DATA"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="45"
      length="76"
      name="TRACK 1 DATA"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="46"
      length="999"
      name="ADITIONAL DATA - ISO"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="47"
      length="999"
      name="ADITIONAL DATA - NATIONAL"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="48"
      length="999"
      name="ADITIONAL DATA - PRIVATE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="49"
      length="3"
      name="CURRENCY CODE, TRANSACTION"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="50"
      length="3"
      name="CURRENCY CODE, SETTLEMENT"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="51"
      length="3"
      name="CURRENCY CODE, CARDHOLDER BILLING"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="52"
      length="16"
      name="PIN DATA"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="53"
      length="16"
      name="SECURITY RELATED CONTROL INFORMATION"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="54"
      length="120"
      name="ADDITIONAL AMOUNTS"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="55"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED ISO"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="56"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED ISO"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="57"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED NATIONAL"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="58"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED NATIONAL"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="59"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED NATIONAL"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="60"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED PRIVATE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="61"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED PRIVATE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="62"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED PRIVATE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="63"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED PRIVATE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="64"
      length="8"
      name="MESSAGE AUTHENTICATION CODE FIELD"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY"/>
  <isofield
      id="65"
      length="1"
      name="BITMAP, EXTENDED"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY"/>
  <isofield
      id="66"
      length="1"
      name="SETTLEMENT CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="67"
      length="2"
      name="EXTENDED PAYMENT CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="68"
      length="3"
      name="RECEIVING INSTITUTION COUNTRY CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="69"
      length="3"
      name="SETTLEMENT INSTITUTION COUNTRY CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="70"
      length="3"
      name="NETWORK MANAGEMENT INFORMATION CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="71"
      length="4"
      name="MESSAGE NUMBER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="72"
      length="4"
      name="MESSAGE NUMBER LAST"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="73"
      length="6"
      name="DATE ACTION"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="74"
      length="10"
      name="CREDITS NUMBER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="75"
      length="10"
      name="CREDITS REVERSAL NUMBER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="76"
      length="10"
      name="DEBITS NUMBER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="77"
      length="10"
      name="DEBITS REVERSAL NUMBER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="78"
      length="10"
      name="TRANSFER NUMBER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="79"
      length="10"
      name="TRANSFER REVERSAL NUMBER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="80"
      length="10"
      name="INQUIRIES NUMBER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="81"
      length="10"
      name="AUTHORIZATION NUMBER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="82"
      length="12"
      name="CREDITS, PROCESSING FEE AMOUNT"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="83"
      length="12"
      name="CREDITS, TRANSACTION FEE AMOUNT"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="84"
      length="12"
      name="DEBITS, PROCESSING FEE AMOUNT"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="85"
      length="12"
      name="DEBITS, TRANSACTION FEE AMOUNT"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="86"
      length="16"
      name="CREDITS, AMOUNT"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="87"
      length="16"
      name="CREDITS, REVERSAL AMOUNT"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="88"
      length="16"
      name="DEBITS, AMOUNT"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="89"
      length="16"
      name="DEBITS, REVERSAL AMOUNT"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="90"
      length="42"
      name="ORIGINAL DATA ELEMENTS"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield
      id="91"
      length="1"
      name="FILE UPDATE CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="92"
      length="2"
      name="FILE SECURITY CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="93"
      length="6"
      name="RESPONSE INDICATOR"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="94"
      length="7"
      name="SERVICE INDICATOR"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="95"
      length="42"
      name="REPLACEMENT AMOUNTS"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="96"
      length="16"
      name="MESSAGE SECURITY CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY"/>
  <isofield
      id="97"
      length="17"
      name="AMOUNT, NET SETTLEMENT"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_AMOUNT"/>
  <isofield
      id="98"
      length="25"
      name="PAYEE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="99"
      length="11"
      name="SETTLEMENT INSTITUTION IDENT CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
      id="100"
      length="11"
      name="RECEIVING INSTITUTION IDENT CODE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield
      id="101"
      length="17"
      name="FILE NAME"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="102"
      length="28"
      name="ACCOUNT IDENTIFICATION 1"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="103"
      length="28"
      name="ACCOUNT IDENTIFICATION 2"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="104"
      length="100"
      name="TRANSACTION DESCRIPTION"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="105"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED ISO USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="106"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED ISO USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="107"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED ISO USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="108"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED ISO USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="109"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED ISO USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="110"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED ISO USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="111"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED ISO USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="112"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="113"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="114"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="115"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="116"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="117"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="118"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="119"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="120"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="121"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="122"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="123"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="124"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="125"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="126"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="127"
      length="999"
      name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield
      id="128"
      length="8"
      name="MAC 2"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY"/>
</isopackager>
```

Comment: In the HEX dump. 1st two characters are the Length stated as 0x00DD. Your Example message actual length is 0x01DD.

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: The explanations made before was clear enough. You need to correct two bytes of hexadecimal message length prefix in the outgoing message packet. Please go on to your packer documentation to see how to deal the message length.